# .NET command line argument bug?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line

I am trying to read command lien argument but it seems there is some kind of bug in .NET.

The parameter which I pass to my console application

/i "C:\Projects\PC\trunk\Simulator\PDF-Source\PDF-Source\bin\Debug\ConversionFiles\dummy.pdf" /o "result"

CommandLine variable return three arguments, but I pass four and values of these arguments messed up.

/i = true

"C:\Projects\PC\trunk\Simulator\PDF-Source\PDF-Source\bin\Debug\ConversionFiles\dummy.pdf" = true

/o = "result"

As you see only the last argument is parsed corectlly. Is this bug?

regards,
Tomas

My code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    Arguments CommandLine = new Arguments(args);
```

Comment: What is Arguments? Some kind of command argument parser?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake :) The problem was in 3rd party class, the problem solved.

Comment: Should look into using and adopting a GNU's getopt approach, there's a .NET version available here http://www.codeplex.com/getopt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in the Arguments class. I bet if you check out args array you will find 4 elements there.